# In GNU Assembler, what does a dot signify at the beginning of a name?

Tags: assembly, linker, gnu, ld, readelf

The following is a line from a microprocessor startup file, intended for input into the GNU assembler *as*:

```
.section  .isr_vector,"a",%progbits
```

Does the dot at the beginning of the name `.isr_vector` mean anything special?  PS: This name is referenced by the GNU linker *ld*.

EDIT:

This name also shows up in readelf output as a *Section Header*:

```
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  ...
  [ 1] .isr_vector       PROGBITS        08000000 008000 0001ac 00   A  0   0  1
```

Comment: It's an assembler directive.

Comment: But my understanding is that `.section` is the directive, but `.isr_vector` is a name.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A dot preceding a name is either an *assembler directive* or a *local label*.

An *assembler directive* tells `as` to do something special, for example `.text` tells it to generate data in the text section of the object file (for things like code and literals that cannot be changed).   There's also directives like `.space` which tell it to allocate empty space in the object file, this is often used to allocate space in the bss section.

On the other hand, we have *local labels* like `.L1` that are used in the code but aren't meant to be exported in the object file and should be hidden from the symbol table.

Comment: +1 Thanks.  Just to clarify: in this case, the dot hides the name?

Comment: @Sabuncu Not necessarily, since it's an argument to the `.section` directive it's probably a section name just like .text, .data, and .bss. The `as` documentation clearly leaves open the possibility for *named sections*

Comment: `.L` docs: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Symbol-Names.html#Symbol-Names

Answer (score 8):

However, I don't agree that it is a local variable. Only symbols prefixing `.L` mean local variables.(The naming convention for local symbol is portable, but some convention is machine-dependent). Type `info as`, navigate to chapter `Symbols` and sub-chapter `Symbol-names`, and you will get it.

I think it is just a symbol, which is the name for a section, and this name is referred in the linker script. You said that you saw this in the microprocessor start-up file. Of course, linking microprocessor start-up files needs linker script. And this name is just used for reference, which may sound weird but is real.

Comment: Section names with a period were just a naming convention to separate system sections from user ones in the [ELF specifications](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/elf/elf.pdf). _Section names with a dot (.) prefix are reserved for the system, although applications may use
these sections if their existing meanings are satisfactory. Applications may use names without
the prefix to avoid conflicts with system sections. The object file format lets one define sections
not in the list above. An object file may have more than one section with the same name._

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thanks! Frankly speaking, I am confused why user-specified section name prefixes with a dot. Now I finally get the official answer.